# How to Automatically Migrate Kotlin synthetic

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a huge project that uses the **synthetic** feature of kotlin, can I migrate it automatically? The manual way is too laborious and time-consuming.

My project is **MVP** so I can't simply migrate with viewbinding.

Comment: What do you mean with "My project is MVP so I can't simply migrate with viewbinding."? replacing synthetics with viewbinding requires minimum code changes I would say and doesn't change any structure of your code and is probably the easiest way to migrate. I don't see how it would affect MVP. I would even say doing it manually should be doable within a day even for the biggest projects. I'm not aware of any automation tools for it, but maybe they exist.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, indeed manual replacement is the safest way.
My project involves thousands or even thousands of xml, and simple view binding replacement requires reference by reference.
For example I need to add view bindings to declare class member variables, if I need to add many different view binding class names
I actually think the form can be automatically replaced with findview by id instead of using specific class names.
I don't know if I made it clear.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand. In any case, view binding doesn't require you to make any changes to your xml files. The migration is pretty simple and straightforward. Please take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration if you haven't read that already

Comment: Yes I have read it, I will think about how to solve it. Thanks a lot anyway~

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ArnoFrost Did you find a tool for that?

Comment: @bob No I haven't